# Load app/activity when phone wakes up from sleep

Tags: android, sleep, wake

I have an android activity, but when the phone goes to sleep(meaning I leave the phone there for a few seconds and then the screen goes black) and I turn it back on, the activity/app disappears(it's still active but i have to press the overview button to come back to the activity/app). How do I get it to come back automatically?

What I want to do is when the phone goes to sleep, when I turn it back on, the app/activity is there as it was when it went to sleep. I've checked up onResume, BroadcastReceivers, WakeLock, KeepScreenOn, Services, but I know I'm not doing it right.

OnResume doesn't work, WakeLock doesn't work, KeepScreenOn, just keeps the screen on and doesn't allow the phone to sleep, I haven't tried Services and BroadcastReceivers, but I thought I should ask here first.

Please help. Thanks.

I have MainActivity.java which opens initially and then starts AdminAddMerchantActivity.java. AdminAddMerchantActivity.java is a navigationView that starts 4 fragments including TimeFragment.java which has a tab layout, a view pager and a pager adapter. TimeFragment.java starts 5 fragments including PriceFragment.java.
Below is the activities lifecycle methods below.

MainActivity.java:

```
...
@Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        Log.d("state", "Pausing Main");
        // Handle countdown stop here
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

            Log.d("state", "Resuming Main");
        currentActivity = sharedPreferences.getString(CURRENT_ACT, "main");
        if(mAuth.getCurrentUser() != null)
        {
            if(currentActivity.equals("confirmFinalOrder"))
            {
                isResumed++;
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ConfirmFinalOrderActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
            else if(currentActivity.equals("merchantDetails"))
            {
                isResumed++;
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MerchantDetailsActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("mid", sharedPreferences.getString("merchantid", ""));
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
            else if(currentActivity.equals("navigation")) {
                isResumed++;
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NavigationActivity.class);
                fragment = sharedPreferences.getString("fragment", "Find Food");
                intent.putExtra("activity", fragment);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
            else if(currentActivity.equals("adminaddnewmerchant"))
            {
                isResumed++;
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AdminAddNewMerchantActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
            else if(currentActivity.equals("searchmerchants"))
            {
                isResumed++;
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SearchMerchantsActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
            else if(currentActivity.equals("settingsuser"))
            {
                isResumed++;
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SettingsActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
            else if(currentActivity.equals("settingsmerchant"))
            {
                isResumed++;
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, SettingsMerchantActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
            else if(currentActivity.equals("sellerregistration"))
            {
                isResumed++;
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SellerRegistrationActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        }
        else{
            if(currentActivity.equals("sellerregistration"))
            {
                isResumed++;
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SellerRegistrationActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
            else if(!sharedPreferences.getString("current activity", "main").equals("login user")
                    && !sharedPreferences.getString("current activity", "main").equals("login merchant"))
            {
                currentActivity = "main";

                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                editor.clear();
                editor.putString(CURRENT_ACT,currentActivity);
                editor.commit();


                Paper.book().write(Prevalent.RememberMeMerchant, "false");
                Paper.book().write(Prevalent.emailKey, "UserEmail");
                Paper.book().write(Prevalent.passwordKey, "UserPassword");
            }
        }

        // Handle countdown start here
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        Log.d("state","Stopping Main");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.d("state", "Destroyed Main");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestart() {
        super.onRestart();
        Log.d("state", "Restarted Main");

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Log.d("state", "Started Main");

    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d("state", "onRestoreInstanceState Main");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        Log.d("state", "onSaveInstanceState Main");
    }
//if the user

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Log.d("state", "back login");

        currentActivity = "main";

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString(CURRENT_ACT,currentActivity);
        editor.commit();
    }
...
```

AdminAddNewMerchantActivity.java:

```
...
@Override
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        if(drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START))
        {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        }
        else{
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
@Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();  // Always call the superclass method first

        // Get the Camera instance as the activity achieves full user focus
        //if (mCamera == null) {
            //initializeCamera(); // Local method to handle camera init
        //}
    }
...
```

PriceFragment.java:

```
...
@Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putInt("scrollPrice", scrollView.getScrollY());
        editor.commit();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        Log.d("onResume", "Resumed");
        super.onResume();

    }
...
```

TimeFragment.java:

```
...
@Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();



    }
...
```

Comment: Attach your activity code with the question.

Comment: Saif, I got an answer. Thanks. I have some debugging to do to track down what's causing my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default Android behavior should do this automatically...

Are you doing something special on the onPause or onStop methods?

And if you're not, can you create a new project via Android Studio and test to see if this behavior persists on the new app?

Comment: I have activity 1, 2 and 3. The apps first activity is Activity 1. Activity 1 spawns 2 and 3. When I am in activity 2 or 3 and the phone falls asleep, the app disappears. However, when I am in activity 2 or 3 and I press the overview button and go back to the app, the app comes back as it was. I have done stuff in Acitivity 1s onResume method that makes it resume properly and go back to activity 2 and 3 when i press the overview button. What else do I have to trouble to get it to work from sleep?

Comment: Activity 1 calls 2 and 3 automatically?
If you are not doing anything "special" on these activities, the Android itself should've resume the correct activity. Here, you can see the [Android lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle#alc)... when the phone falls sleep, the activity goes througn onPause and onStop, when the phone wakes up, it goes through onStart and onResume..

Comment: I added all my lifecycle methods for each activity/fragment above. MainActivity.java stays open when the app goes to sleep and comes back, but AdminAddNewMerchantActivity.java doesn't. I checked if the app goes back in to my MainActivity.java's onResume method when the phone goes to sleep, but it doesn't

Comment: You're calling finish on MainActivity when you open AdminAddNewMerchantActivity, so when the phone goes to sleep and wakes up, it should goes direct to AdminAddNewMerchantActivity's onResume. Maybe it's losing reference to its fragments? When the phone wakes, are you seeing your phone home screen or are you seeing a blank white screen?
Can you put logs on onViewCreated and onDestroyView on the fragments to see it there are being destroyed when the phone goes to sleep?

Comment: Removing finish() from my mainActivity worked! thanks man! I appreciate your help! This was bothering me until you helped :D